# Подключение WMS слоя на Yandex

Tags: yandex-maps-api, geoserver

Есть ли стандартная возможность подключения WMS слоя на Yandex Maps API? 
[Например как у 2GIS](http://api.2gis.ru/doc/maps/ru/manual/raster-layers/#dgtilelayer.wms)

Если нет, то как можно реализовать?

Comment: А этот пример смотрели? https://github.com/dimik/ymaps/tree/master/layer-wms

Comment: Reni спасибо! Уже как раз его разбираю.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно отображать на карте слои из других картографических сервисов, то на 
мой взгляд возможно Вам подойдет пример : https://github.com/and-hom/wwmap/blob/master/frontend/js/map.v2.js в ф-ции addLayer
А вот так выглядит карта с подключенными слоями вживую: https://wwmap.ru/map.htm
Кроме того есть пример в документации api https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map

Если подробнее:

1. Нужно создать объект layer. Не забываем указать нужную проекцию, иначе координаты слегка исказятся, и это будет заметно не сразу. Какую именно проекцию указывать, зависит от источника. Я использовал sphericalMercator с OSM, например. Вот тут подробнее https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/projection.sphericalMercator-docpage/. По умолчанию используется wgs84. Можно задать диапазон зума от 0 до 17, если источник не покрывает все масштабы. Также важно не забыть указать копирайты.
   tilesUrlTemplate в данном примере - шаблон URL для тайлов карты. Например, 'http://a.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/%z/%x/%y.png'.

```
var layer = function () {
        var layer = new ymaps.Layer(tilesUrlTemplate, {
            projection: ymaps.projection.sphericalMercator
        });
        layer.getCopyrights = function () {
            return ymaps.vow.resolve(copyright);
        };
        layer.getZoomRange = function () {
            return ymaps.vow.resolve([lower_scale, upper_scale]);
        };
        return layer;
    };
```

2. Добавляем слой в хранилище, где key - строка, по которой мы будем получать слой, например, "default#osm"

```
    ymaps.layer.storage.add(key, layer);
    ymaps.mapType.storage.add(key, new ymaps.MapType(name, [key]));
```

3. Используем

```
myMap.controls.add(
        new ymaps.control.TypeSelector([
                'osm#standard',
                'yandex#satellite'
            ]
        )
    );
```

Comment: Маленькая ремарка: Ваше сообщение не тянет на полноценный ответ - это комментарий. Я понимаю, Вы не имеете в силу невысокого рейтинга писать комментарии, поэтому было бы хорош, если бы кроме ссылок добавили бы краткий пересказ того, что там предлагается